# How do I get the Combat Engineer ribbon?

Tags: xbox-360, gears-of-war-3

I am trying to get the "Combat Engineer" ribbon in Horde 2.0 mode of Gears of War 3.  The gears wiki says

> Combat Engineer: Build, repair, and or upgrade 5 fortifications during wave-half time.

I am playing gears by myself and have purchased 5 different items in between waves numerous time but I never seem to get this ribbon (I have received it once but don't remember when).  Does it only count if I buy barriers?  Or can I buy decoys and turrets as well?  Do I have to be playing co-op with someone else or can I get the ribbon while playing by myself?  Does it matter which map I use?  Just general help on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Rules:

- You cannot get the ribbon while playing alone. There must be other people playing with you. Plugging in a second controller might help, haven't tried it.
- You can only get the ribbon once per spawn or once you fail a wave. So, if you have gotten one ribbon, there is no second ribbon in the same life. So , if you are only after the ribbon, just die, or restart manually after getting the ribbon, repeat until 100, which will give you the Infinite Ammo Mutator.
- Which map you play does not matter.

Comment: I think you need to get 200 combat engineer ribbons to unlock the mutator. And you can earn it once per wave.

Answer (score 0):

The map you use has no impact.